# Integral of a Gaussian times a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have been looking as crazy for a closed-form expression of integrals of the following nature

$$\int_0^\infty\text{d}x\,e^{-(a+x)^2}\frac{x^m}{(x^2+b)^n}$$

where $a,b>0$ and $n$ and $m$ are positive integers. Its form looks simple enough to have a closed-form expression, but I have failed in every thing I tried. Does there exist a closed form for arbitrary $n,m$ or, at least, for $n=8$ and $m=3,5,7$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Its form looks simple enough": with $n=0$, this is already more complex than an incomplete Gamma integral.

Comment: If I am right, you can establish the recurrence $I(m, n)=-(I(m, n-1)+aI(m-1,n-1))/(n-1)$ by parts and reduce to integrals with $n=0$ or $n=1,m=0$, using polynomial division.

Comment: I am afraid the recurrence relation you aim to is not possible, since it involves the integration of the Gaussian part, giving an error function (not another Gaussian). Trying integrating by parts the other way around I get a recurrence relation, but depending on higher values of $m$, so it is not useful either. Still, thank you for the tip.

Comment: No the integration is on part of the rational fraction.

Comment: Great, integrating $\frac{x}{(x^2+b)^n}$ and deriving the rest I arrive to the recursion relation $I(m,n)=1/(2n-2)\left[(m-1)I(m-2,n-1)-2aI(m-1,n-1)-2I(m,n-1)\right]$ for $m>1$. Let's see if I can reach somewhere with this, thank you so much!

Comment: No, it looks like it takes to an equally difficult place, since one needs to compute $I(1,1)$ and $I(0,1)$, which are still too complex to get something straightforwardly